# How difficult is it to bring someone back from the dead?

Tags: the-sims-3

My partner accidentally died. I would like to resurrect her and I read up on the oh my ghost opportunity. Does it take long and is this oppertunity missable?

Also, my partner was the cook, can she make the ambrosia while dead? Can dead Sims cook?

Comment: "Can dead Sims cook?" Wow, this game has changed a lot since I played the first version about 15 years ago...

Comment: @bwarner ravens answer shows that a whole lot has changed.

Comment: "Can dead sims cook" would also have got my vote in this month's "Dwarf Fortress" competition for a weird question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The opportunity isn't miss-able (unless you have opportunities turned off), and will happen on it's own automatically after enough days pass by.

Once you have your  playable ghost (by completing the opportunity) your deceased sim is able to do everything they could do in life. Yes, [everything](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_baby).

This means she is able to cook just as well as when she was alive; if you have the ingredients for ambrosia, all she needs to do is cook and eat the recipe and she'll be returned to her mortal coil.